# Encrypted messaging app using QR codes for key exchange

Tags: key-exchange, instant-messaging, end-to-end-encryption

I remember seeing an encrypted messaging app a while ago that offered using QR codes to exchange encryption keys between the users. Of course, this only worked when the people met physically, but added an interesting layer on top of the usual key-exchange protocols. However, I cannot recall which app it was and am unable to find it again (perhaps the feature has been removed since). Perhaps Riot when it was still Riot?

Does anyone know such an app that uses QR codes to transfer keys or secret data in general?

And is it a good idea in general - I don't mean exchanging *all* keys since they might soon run out in a chatty conversation, but perhaps some secret seed that is then used as `KDF(secret_seed, DHE_key)` after the usual ephemeral Diffie-Hellmann stuff, to derive the actual message encryption key.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that these were **encryption** keys, since there should be no long term encryption key (i.e. it should change often - see [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy)). Instead these were likely keys for **authentication** as the base for ensuring that future  key exchanges (for encryption keys) happens with the correct peer and not some man in the middle. There seem to be multiple apps which support QR code for this, like (found after some quick googling) Threema or Session.

Comment: I know about Threema scanning QR codes to mutually authenticate users, but this was really something different. Or my memory is failing me miserably which I hope I am still too young to be the case :-)

Comment: You may be thinking of 'safety codes' used by Signal, which are based on the unique ephemeral  keys used for encrypting a conversation, which themselves are based on the underlying long-term public keys of the participants in the conversation.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139596/signal-protocol-implementations-pub-key-authentication-and-inspectability-all for more info.